# copy as bitmap do not work in 11.2 (was SE Uploaded do not capture cell as image (PP) in 11.2)

Tags: image, windows

**Update**

Thanks to comment by  Szabolcs below. It seems the reason SEUploader do not capture `image pp` is that `copy as` bitmap do not work on 11.1

[image]

Here is the same thing on 11.1.1 and it works there.

[image]

**Original question**

I just updated to 11.2 on windows 7. I noticed that latest [SE Uploader](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools) do not capture an image of selected cell when clicking on the `image (pp)` button but only capture the image when clicking on `image` button.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

On 11.1.1 both buttons work.  I am also using latest version of SE Uploader (version 130)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This is Windows specific. On OS X, it does work (and the pp methods are actually different on the two systems).

Comment: Please try Edit -> Copy As -> Bitmap, then paste it back into the notebook. Does it work for the same cells?

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried it on same cell I show above. When I past it back, nothing shows up. Just blank cell. !  But when I do the same in 11.1.1 it  works!  So this might be a bug in 11.2. Will post screen shot.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like a bug.  (I don't have 11.2 on Windows yet, so can't try.)  Now that there is a way to demonstrate it without the uploader palette, can you report it?

Comment: @Szabolcs just send email to Wolfram support. Linked to this post.

Comment: I won't be of any help either. I don't use Mathematica on Windows and if it's Windows-specific I'm going to need someone that tests and provides a fix. But it seems anyway that it's due to some issue in Mathematica. Just wanted to comment that I've seen your question.

Comment: On windows 10 with version 11.2.0 it works if you paste in paint, and copy from there.

Comment: The problem is that all alpha values are 0. So `Image[(image // ImageData)[[All, All, 1 ;; 3]]]` makes it appear